# Split column into multiple columns or separate "tables" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, split, multiple-columns

I'm very new to python and don't have much of a clue what I'm doing. I have a series of data that describes the performance ('Leistung') of different people ('Leistungserbringer'). Each performance is also linked to a specific value ('Taxpunke'). I'd like to display the top 10 performances for each person, defined by the value of the performance.

```
byleistung = df.groupby('Leistungserbringer') 
df2 = byleistung['Taxpunkte'].describe()
df2.sort_values(['mean'], ascending=[False])

                count   mean        std         min     25%     50%     75%     max
Leistungserbringer      
Larsson William 6188.0  99.799108   231.765598  2.50    15.81   31.61   111.71  3909.72
Karlsson Oliwer 5645.0  93.344057   277.989424  3.61    15.81   31.61   94.83   9122.68
McGregor Sean   1250.0  89.100800   136.175528  3.61    18.35   34.78   111.71  998.64
Groeneveld Arno 4045.0  84.859498   202.230230  1.93    15.81   31.61   63.23   3323.52
Heepe Simon     3776.0  82.662950   359.970010  3.61    15.81   31.61   50.47   13597.60
Bitar Wahib     7814.0  72.190337   142.399537  3.61    15.81   31.61   61.75   3634.15
Cox James       4746.0  72.036013   132.240942  2.50    15.81   31.61   50.65   1664.40
Carvalho Tomas  7415.0  60.868030   156.889297  2.86    15.81   15.81   41.50   2099.20
```

The 'count' is the amount of performances the specific person did. In total there are 330 different performances these people have done. As an example:

```
byleistung = df.groupby('Leistung') 
byleistung['Taxpktwert'].describe()

                                           count    unique  top     freq
Leistung                
'(+) %-Zuschlag für Notfall B, '              2       1     KVG     2
'+ Bronchoalveoläre Lavage (BAL)'             1       1     KVG     1
'+ Bürstenabstrich bei Bronchoskopie'         8       1     KVG     8
'+ Endobronchialer Ultraschall mit Punktion'  1       1     KVG     1
'XOLAIR Trockensub 150 mg c Solv Durchstf'    109     1     KVG     109
```

my DataFrame looks like this (has 40'000 more rows):

```
df.head()

Leistungserbringer  Anzahl  Leistung    AL      TL  Taxpktwert  Taxpunkte
0   Groeneveld Arno     12  'Beratung'  147.28  87.47   KVG     234.75
1   Groeneveld Arno     12  'Konsilium' 147.28  87.47   KVG     234.75
2   Groeneveld Arno     12  'Ultra'     147.28  87.47   KVG     234.75
3   Groeneveld Arno     12  'O2-Druck'  147.28  87.47   KVG     234.75
4   Groeneveld Arno     12  'Funktion'  147.28  87.47   KVG     234.75
```

I want my endresult to kinda look like this for each of the people. The ranking should be based on the product of counts per performance ('Anzahl') * value ('Taxpunkte'):

```
Leistungserbringer    Leistung  Anzahl  Taxpunkte   Total Taxpkt    
Larsson William       1         x        a           x*a
                      2         y        b           y*b
                      .
                      .
                      10        z        c           z*c
...

McGregor Sean         1         x        a           x*a
                      2         y        b           y*b
                      .
                      .
                      10        z        c           z*b
```

Any hints or recommendations of approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at pandas [pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Comment: @VinceP thank you!

Comment: @JariKlingler problem solved?

Comment: @KacperWolkowski I'm trying it with `df.groupby('Leistungserbringer')['Leistung','Total Taxpkt',‌​'Anzahl'].head(10)` at the moment, but the names for the people disappear with `.head()`. If it wold display the names it would show them for every row I imagine, which isn't a great format.